# Attaching picture from camera and gallery to email

Tags: java, android

How to attach a captured/stored image to email as an attachment?

Code for capturing image from camera,

[capture image from camera code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCFGJ.png)

Code for retrieving image from gallery,

[image from gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1MAU.png)

Comment: Instead of attaching your code into an image file, post the code directly as text.

Comment: i was trying to do that but stack flow is complaining about index of my code

Answer (score 0):

Use can simply use an implicit Intent to attach the image,

```
   Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");

   //set your subject
   shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email Subject"); 
   //set your message    
   shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email Messasge"); 

   String imagePath = "specify_the_image_path_here"

   File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);
   Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);

   shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: public void onSelectImageGallery(Intent data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        ivImage.setImageBitmap(mPresenter.getScaledBitmap(picturePath, 50, 50));

    }